# Hyper-V RemoteFX with Windows 8 Pro?

Tags: windows, windows-8, virtualization, hyper-v

It is possible to use RemoteFX with Hyper-V on Windows 8 Pro?

According to http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enterprise/products-and-technologies/windows-8/enterprise-edition.aspx it looks like that is possible to use it only with Enterprise edition. After some searching over the internet it even look like that is not possible with Windows 8 at all. (Windows Server is required).

Can somebody bring a bit of light to this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

It appears from my final release of Windows 8 Professional that RemoteFX is not an option under Hyper-V like it is with Server 2012.

Comment: in my Windows 8 Enterprise is not this option either..